# Is the partial supremum is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $f: K \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, where $K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a compact set. Define $f_t : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be $f_t := f(t,\cdot)$, and let $g(t) = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f_t(x)$. Assume $g(t) < \infty$ for every $t \in K$. Then the question is if $g$ is continuous as a map $K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Is the answer is true (I suspect it is based on trying out simple examples), a proof sketch or a reference for the result will be great?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n=d=1$, $K=[0,1]$, and $f(t,x)=-e^{-tx}$. Since $f$ is a composition of continuous functions, it too is continuous, and since $f(t,x)\leq 0$ it follows that also $g(t)\leq 0<\infty$, as required. However, $f(0,x)=-1$ implies that $g(0)=-1$ whereas for all $t>0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(t,x)=0$ implies that $g(t)=0$. Thus
$$
\lim_{t\searrow 0}g(t)\not=g(0),
$$
showing that $g$ is discontinuous in this case.

---

The intuition behind this counterexample, and why it may seem counterintuitive at first, is that continuity of $g(t)$ is closely related to the idea that the region where $f(t,\cdot)$ is largest should vary "continuously" in $t$ (e.g., $f(t,\cdot)$ could be peaking in a small interval whose endpoints move continuously in $t$) - and this latter property (formalized properly) does follow from the continuity of $f(\cdot,\cdot)$. But even if this region varies continuously, that is not sufficient to conclude continuity of $g(t)$ because we can send the region off to infinity in "finite time" as a function of $t$, which will cause the slice $f(t,\cdot)$ corresponding to the limiting value of $t$ to "lose track" of where the supremum went, creating the potential for a discontinuity to develop in $g(t)$. Compare with Example 4 ("escape to horizontal infinity") of [this blog post by Terry Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/).

Continue reading past Example 4 in that blog post and you will see examples of other types of "escape to infinity". It's interesting to think through what additional conditions in this problem are necessary to exclude the various ways of escape to infinity until the desired conclusion (continuity of $g(t)$) holds.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is great.

Answer (score 3):

The result is false. For a counterexample, consider $f:[0,1]\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(t,x) := \sin (tx)$. Define $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(t) := \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f(t,x)$. It is not hard to show that $f$ and $g$ satisfy the required assumptions of the statement. Furthermore, if $t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, then it is not hard to show that there is some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sin (tx) = 1$. Consequently, it follows that

$$g(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & t\in (0,1], \\ 0 & t\in \{0\}. \end{cases}$$

So $g$ is not continuous at $0$, and is consequently not continuous.